# How to calculate number of reads/writes going on in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0, datastax

We want to calculate how many records are written/read to our cassandra cluster on per sec or day basis without Opscenter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opscenter is just reading the standard JMX presented by C* so you could do the same thing. The mbeans you are most likely interested in are

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Read,name=Latency : Count
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Write,name=Latency : Count
```

Grab these from all the nodes and you have your read and write counts.

Comment: Am trying to add this in zabbix..... jmx["org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Read,name=Latency : Count"]. It is not working for me. Do you have any idea?

Comment: it has been a while :) but for googlers: jmx["org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Read,name=Latency",Count].

Comment: Voted down by mistake. This is a really counter of requests. sorry.